# Returning to a different line than the starting point within a while True-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Edit: problem solved in comments. Have not tried check-marked answer.

I have used a while True-loop to go back to the starting point when an invalid answer is given. This works great for my first if-elif-else-statement. But if i want a second if-elif-else-statement, inside one of the previous conditions, i cant figure out how to send an invalid answer back to the start og the second if-elif-else-statement instead of first. Heres my code (problem in bold):

```
while True:
    a = input("Do you want Stackoverflow to help me with this problem? Yes/No: ")
    if a == "Yes":
        b = input("I need a second if-statement to make my point. Is that ok? Yes/No: ")
        if b == "Yes":
            print("How very nice of you. My problem is with the else condition")
            break
        elif b == "No":
            print("why not? I'm not asking for much")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid answer. Write Yes/No.") #**Here is my problem. I want an invalid answer to return to line 4, not line 2.**
    elif a == "No":
        print("Ok. Thats too bad for me")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid answer. Write Yes/No.")
```

Comment: Add another `while True` at line 4 then fix indent rest of the code

Comment: @mhhabib this fixed it. I thought i had tried this and got error, but i guess not. Might have forgot to fix indent. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the code, it might be worthwhile to break it up into several functions. One option would be to put the second loop in a separate function, particularly if you can give it a good name. Another good way would be to make a separate function that asks Yes/No questions with the loop, so that the main code can just deal with a Yes/No and doesn't need to worry about looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the efficient solution but is simple enough to understand and implement.

```py
exit_first_loop = False
exit_second_loop = False

while not exit_first_loop:
    a = input("Do you want Stackoverflow to help me with this problem? Yes/No: ")
    if a == "Yes":
    
        while not exit_second_loop:
            b = input("I need a second if-statement to make my point. Is that ok? Yes/No: ")
            if b == "Yes":
                print("How very nice of you. My problem is with the else condition")
                exit_first_loop = True
                exit_second_loop = True
            elif b == "No":
                print("why not? I'm not asking for much")
                exit_first_loop = True
                exit_second_loop = True
            else:
                print("Invalid answer. Write Yes/No.") #**Now you will be sent to 4.**
    elif a == "No":
        print("Ok. Thats too bad for me")
        exit_first_loop = True
    else:
        print("Invalid answer. Write Yes/No.")
```

Answer (score 0):

From @mhhabib comment:
Add another while True at line 4 then fix indent rest of the code

I also had to add a new break-statement in line 14 to get desired result, stopping the loop after getting.

Fixed code, with edits in #.

````
while True:
    a = input("Do you want Stackoverflow to help me with this problem? Yes/No: ")
    if a == "Yes":
        while True: # added extra while True, and fixed indent.
            b = input("I need a second if-statement to make my point. Is that ok? Yes/No: ")
            if b == "Yes":
                print("How very nice of you. My problem is with the else condition")
                break
            elif b == "No":
                print("why not? I'm not asking for much")
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid answer. Write Yes/No.")
        break # added break (one indent back) so first loop doesnt start after second is broken.
    elif a == "No":
        print("Ok. Thats too bad for me")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid answer. Write Yes/No."```
````

Answer (score 0):

In terms of code organisation, it'd probably be worthwhile to reorganise the code into separate functions; one possible piece of functionality to separate out would be the "ask in a loop until a valid answer is given"; then the main code wouldn't need to worry about the retries at all:

```
def ask(question, options):
    options_text = "/".join(options)
    while True:
        ans = input("%s %s:" % (question, options_text)
        if ans in options:
            return ans
        print("Invalid answer. Write %s" % options_text)

a = ask("Do you want Stackoverflow to help me with this problem?", ("Yes", "No"))
if a == "Yes":
    b = ask("I need a second if-statement to make my point. Is that ok?", ("Yes", "No"))
    if b == "Yes":
        print("How very nice of you. My problem is with the else condition")
    else:  # b == "No"
        print("why not? I'm not asking for much")
else:  # a == "No"
    print("Ok. Thats too bad for me")
```